# How to send android notification wthout using firebase only communication between app, php and mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

Help here does any one knows how to make an android application that automatically receives notification when it checks in mysql database and finds that there is a new entry in the table without using firebase the communication is only between the android app,PHP and mysql

Comment: use background service

Answer (score -1):

> use GCM or other library for that